# Cannot get Process to Execute before input stream is closed

Tags: c#

The code is supposed to run python and accept python commands from the `StreamWriter`. But only closing the `StreamWriter` causes the code to execute - that's no good:

```
private Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "python",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false
};
p.Start();

//new Task(WriteInputTask).Start();

private StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
sw.AutoFlush = true; //does nothing
sw.Write("print('Printing from python')" + Environment.NewLine);
sw.Flush(); //does nothing
sw.Close(); //NOW console shows "Printing from python"
```

I don't want to have to restart python and re-import everything (especially arcpy which takes half a minute to import) every time I want to issue new commands. `Close()` does something with the buffer that `Flush()` does not.

Comment: Unless you want to restrict your audience to only those people who actually have a Python interpreter installed and who are willing to write both a Python script and a whole program around your brief example here (hint: that's not going to be very many people, if even one), you need to provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: I will confirm that the code as given doesn't run (runtime error @ start because of the encoding set on stdout without a redirect (at least that is what my exception says).  I believe I know what the problem is, it will take me a few mins to fix up  a working example.

Comment: @Dweeberly I apologize for the error in the example - I tried to simplify the example from my code as much as possible. Thank you for your suggestion I have not tried adding any switches though briefly looked through the docs to see what was available. I'll give this a shot as soon as I have a free moment.

Comment: @PeterDuniho BTW I bookmarked that link and will refer to it before writing any more questions. My best practice is to ask questions only when I am desperate. I spent half a day on this one before resorting to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry took a little longer than I expected.  This is a python oddity (i.e. you don't see this behavior in cmd).  You need to add the '-i' switch to python when you start it.  Here is a full working example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace stackoverflow1 {
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var exe = "python";
        var arguments = "-i";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
            FileName = exe,
            Arguments = arguments,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
        };

        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
            delegate (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", exe, outLine.Data);
                });

        p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
            delegate (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs errLine) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + errLine.Data);
                });

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();

        StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
        sw.AutoFlush = true; //does nothing

        if (exe == "cmd") {
            sw.WriteLine("echo hello");
            sw.WriteLine("echo 2+2");
            sw.WriteLine("echo Goodbye");
            }
        else { // assume python
            sw.WriteLine("print('Hello')");
            sw.WriteLine("2+2");
            sw.WriteLine("print('Printing from python')");
            sw.WriteLine("print('Goodbye')");
            }
        sw.Flush();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Closing");
        sw.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've run this example and, with some very tiny tweaks to fit what I'm doing, it works like a boss. I may get to keep my job after all. Thanks.